# A table with a sidebar

Tags: tables, tabu, sidebar

How can I make a similar table as the below image with a sidebar pointing to some rows is the table?
[image]

My attempt to create something similar

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, positioning, fit, shapes.misc}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{HMM}\label{tab1}
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline\\[-1.5ex]
blablablabla & blablablabla & blablablabla \\[0.5ex]
\hline\\[-1.5ex]
blabla& blabla & blabla\tikzmark{a}\\[0.5ex]
\hline
blabla& blabla & blabla \\[0.5ex]
\hline
blabla& blabla & blabla \\[0.5ex]
\hline
blabla& blabla & blabla \tikzmark{b}\\[0.5ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\draw[very thick] ($(pic cs:a) + (2.5em,0)$) -| ($(pic cs:a) + (4.5em,0)$) -- ($(pic cs:b) + (5em,0)$) -- ($(pic cs:b) + (3em,0)$) --($(pic cs:a) + (2.5em,0)$); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

• Note this is a Q&A site, not a please do this for me service. What do you have so far.

Comment: Probably you can get an idea from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/187006/134144 and here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182693/134144

Comment: @albert I added my code which is not at all what I want.

Comment: @leandriis I made an example code using the links you provided but it is not like the table I would like to make especially I would like to be able to write in the box in the right hand side of the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the modified tikzmark command from [Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182693/134144) you can get the following that might serve as a point to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

%%%%% modified tikzmark command from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/182693/134144
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, anchor=base] (#1) {#2};}
%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{HMM}\label{tab1}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|@{}p{1cm}@{}|c|}
\cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
blablablabla & blablablabla & blablablabla & & \parbox[t]{3mm}{\multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{rotated text}}}\\
\cline{1-3}
blabla& blabla & blabla &\tikzmark{a}{} &\\
\cline{1-3}
blabla& blabla & blabla & &\\
\cline{1-3}
blabla& blabla & blabla & &\\
\cline{1-3}
blabla& blabla & blabla & \tikzmark{b}{} &\\
\cline{1-3}
blabla& blabla & blabla & &\\
\cline{1-3}
blabla& blabla & blabla & &\\
\cline{1-3} \cline{5-5}
\end{tabular}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] {
  \draw[<->] (a) -- ++(0:1cm);
  \draw[<->] (b) -- ++(0:1cm);
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: one small question: how can I make this horizontal half lines between rows in my table?

Comment: @Dalek: You can use the  `arydshln` package that includes the `\hdashline` and `\cdashline` commands as equivalents to `\hline` cna `\cline`.