# How to draw a line that passes through rows and columns of a table?

Tags: tables, graphics, formatting

Could someone tell me how can I draw a line that pass through  some of the columns and rows of a table like the one on this example?

e.g. a line crossing a,b,c row

```
\documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{float}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
        a & b & c \\
        \hline
        d & e & f \\
        \hline
        h & i & j \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to use Ti*k*Z and `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
        \tikzmarknode{a}{a} & b & \tikzmarknode{c}{c} \\
        \hline
        d & e & f \\
        \hline
        h & i & j \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \draw[thick,red,-stealth] ([xshift=-1ex]a.west) -- ([xshift=1ex]c.east);
\end{tikzpicture}%  

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that the syntax of `\tikzmarknode` is `\tikzmarknode{<id>}{<content>}`, where `id` is an identifier and `content` is the content. So, if you want a `1`, say instead of the `a`, you could use the same identifier and only change the second argument, `\tikzmarknode{a}{1}`. Then there will be a 1 in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
        \tikzmarknode{a}{1} & 2 & \tikzmarknode{c}{3} \\
        \hline
        \tikzmarknode{goat}{d} & e & f \\
        \hline
        \tikzmarknode{duck}{h} & i & j \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
 \path[left color=blue,right color=red] 
  ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=-0.3pt]a.west) rectangle ([xshift=1ex,yshift=0.3pt]c.east);
 \draw[red,shorten >=-0.2ex,shorten <=-0.2ex]  (goat.north) -- (duck.south);
\end{tikzpicture}%  

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This example is also to illustrate that with Ti*k*Z you can go far beyond monochrome lines.

Comment: Thanks. Does this Tikz feature works only for letters ? I tried with numbers but doesn't displays what's expected

Comment: @user178403 It works for everything. Note that the syntax of `\tikzmarknode` is `\tikzmarknode{<id>}{<content>}`, where `id` is an identifier and `content` is the content. So, if you want a `1`, say instead of the `a`, you could use the same identifier and only change the second argument, `\tikzmarknode{a}{1}`. Then there will be a 1 in the table.

Comment: Do you know why I have the error `Package pgf Error: No shape named as aa is know`? `aa` is the name gave instead of `a`

Comment: Also in the line where is `\tikzmarknode{aa}{1}` marks `Undefined control sequence`

Comment: @user178403 This probably means you were trying to use a node named `aa` but did not create one. You can only use `aa` in a path if you have previously created a node of that name, i.e. with this id. Note also that if you have a very old TeX installation, your version of `tikzmark` may not yet contain `\tikzmarknode`, so you'd need to update the installation (which is a good idea regardless).

Comment: I see. Thank you again.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat, how can I draw a vertical line? I did tried and changed to `north`, `south`  but the result was an inclined arrow, not a straight line. And when I change to `rectangle`instead of `--` the result was indeed a rectangle.

Comment: @user178403 I added an example of a vertical line to the second example.

Answer (score 7):

With only basic tools:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hhline{|---|}
\noalign{\vskip \dimexpr1.5ex + 1pt-0.4pt\relax}
\hhline{>{\arrayrulecolor{Crimson}}--->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|}
\noalign{\vskip\dimexpr-1.5ex- 1pt\relax}
    a & b & c \\
    \hhline{|---|}
    d & e & f \\
    \hhline{|---|}
    h & i & j \\
    \hhline{|---|}
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Why when I add `\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}` marks an error saying "Option clash for package xcolor" ? I then deleted `usepackage{xcolor}` but the error doesn't go away, it's still there

Comment: Probably because you already load  `xcolor`,  possibly via some package (TikZ, beamer, …), and with another or no option at all. A simple remedy consists in passing this option through the `\documentclass`.

Comment: @Sebastiano: Yes, I am rather nitpicky about the correct writing of proper names. B.t.w., do you know that since our Revolution, names with a particle have been shortened of their particles (and some people were shortened, too…)?

Comment: This afternoon I read a question about math.SE. about how to spell this name :) But I like the old version of the name. To write de l'Hospital makes me think about the hospital :-)

Comment: Yes. However in modern French the 'o' takes a circumflex,  non come l'ospedale. At the time of the Marquis, it was with  an 's', and as, it is a proper name, I think it's better to keep the old spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {0,2,...,6} \draw[thick] (\x,0)--(\x,6);
    \foreach \x in {0,2,...,6} \draw[thick] (0,\x)--(6,\x);

    \node at (1.5,1.5) {$g$};
   \node at (3.5,1.5) {$h$};
  \node at (5.5,1.5) {$i$};
   \node at (1.5,3.5) {$d$};
    \node at (3.5,3.5) {$e$};
   \node at (5.5,3.5) {$f$};
    \node at (1.5,5.5) {$a$};
   \node at (3.5,5.5) {$b$};
    \node at (5.5,5.5) {$c$};


    \color{magenta}
    \draw[thick,-] (8,2.5)--(0,2.5);

    \color{cyan}
    \draw[thick,-] (5,6)--(5,0);

    \color{green}
    \draw[thick,->] (.5,0)--(.5,7);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Displays

[image]

NOTE. In this case I'm not using the environment `table` as you did. Take this as an alternative to display the same result.

---

I did this, inspired by the answer by @JoséCarlosSantos in his answer to my question [How can I add this arrows and numbers inside a table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518313/how-can-i-add-this-arrows-and-numbers-inside-a-table)